# saving in sdcard saves file in wrong place

Tags: android

I have a file

```
String filename="MEMS.backup";
```

I use this to save:

```
InputStream myInput;

         File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
         File directory = new File (sdCard, "Myfolder"); 

            try {


 myInput = new FileInputStream(MyApplication.getAppContext().getFilesDir().getParentFile().getPath()+"/databases/MEMS");

                // Create the folder if it doesn't exist:
                if (!directory.exists()) 
                {
                    directory.mkdirs();
                } 

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(directory.getPath()+
                         filename);
```

and this to load:

```
OutputStream myOutput;

        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File directory = new File (sdCard, "Myfolder");


        try {

myOutput= new FileOutputStream(MyApplication.getAppContext().getFilesDir().getParentFile().getPath()+"/databases/MEMS");

InputStream myInputs = new FileInputStream(directory.getPath()+filename);
```

The problem is that it creates "Myfolder" in sdcard but it is empty.

And the file "MEMS" goes just in sdcard (should be in Myfolder).

And the name of the file is MyfolderMEMS instead of MEMS.

I can't figure my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the problem is File separator is missing, try with this,

```
OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(directory.getPath()+File.separator+
                         filename);
```

or try with this,

```
OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(directory.getPath()+"/"+
                         filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(directory.getPath()+
                         filename);
```

with

```
File file = new File(directory, filename); 
OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Comment: :Thanks for the answer.I chose the other because I liked it better.:) (I upvoted)

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below code for creating new file in myfolder

```
 File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 File directory = new File (sdCard, "Myfolder"); 


if( !directory.exists() )
    directory.mkdirs();

File f = new File( directory, "my_file.jpg" );
OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(f);
```

Comment: :Thanks for the help.I liked the other answer better :)